# Web API and Async/Await Benefits on a Single Core Machine

Tags: c#, azure, task-parallel-library, asp.net-web-api

I had asked a question in a different [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22134968/issue-image-corruption-using-graphics-drawimage-with-task-parallel-library) about issues with GDI+ in TPL (async/await) and the discussion turned to the question of whether or not there even were any benefits to using TPL for this.

So I'm trying to understand the answer to that here.

The scenario is roughly this:

- A Web API controller/method receives an image upload
- A method which resizes the image and uploads it to azure is called multiple times for various sizes (<10)
- The method returns a Uri for each resized-and-uploaded image
- A response is returned to the Web API client

Note that this will likely run on a single core machine so there is no benefit to be gained by running all the resizes in parallel (to, say, shorten the overall length of the request).

But I'm under the impression that wrapping all the various resizes into a method and running that asynchronously *will* at least return the Web API thread to the pool, temporarily, to process another request (while a regular thread runs the resizing tasks), and that that is a good thing.  The code would look like this:

```
public Dictionary<ProfilePhotoSize, Uri> ProcessImages(Stream photoStream)
{
    var imgUris = new Dictionary<ProfilePhotoSize, Uri>()
    {
        ProfilePhotoSize.FiveHundredFixedWidth, ResizeAndUpload(ProfilePhotoSize.FiveHundredFixedWidth, photoStream)},
        ProfilePhotoSize.Square220, ResizeAndUpload(ProfilePhotoSize.Square220, photoStream)},
        ProfilePhotoSize.Square140, ResizeAndUpload(ProfilePhotoSize.Square140, photoStream)},
        ProfilePhotoSize.Square80, ResizeAndUpload(ProfilePhotoSize.Square80, photoStream)},
        ProfilePhotoSize.Square50, ResizeAndUpload(ProfilePhotoSize.Square50, photoStream)}
    };

    return imgUris;
}
```

and...

```
var photoUris = await Task.Run(() => _photoService.ProcessImages(photoStream);
```

So the question is - am I off base?  Maybe the theory is sound, but it's not implemented quite right (perhaps I need to use ConfigureAwait)?

What's the reality here?

Comment: Have a look here http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-and-where-concurrent-asynchronous-io-with-asp-net-web-api Also why not use Azure WebJobs for resizing images and uploading to Azure storage?

Comment: @MatijaGrcic Reading your link, it seems to support my understanding - yes?  As for Azure WebJobs, we may be moving away from Azure but I will look at it in case we don't...

Answer (score 6):

> But I'm under the impression that wrapping all the various resizes into a method and running that asynchronously will at least return the Web API thread to the pool, temporarily, to process another request (while a regular thread runs the resizing tasks), and that that is a good thing.

No, not really. If you had true asynchronous work to do, then yes, you'd get a scalability benefit from using `async` and `await`. However, your work is CPU-bound, so code like this:

> ```
> var photoUris = await Task.Run(() => _photoService.ProcessImages(photoStream);
> ```

just ends up using another thread pool thread (`Task.Run`), allowing the request thread to return to the thread pool. So it's actually *adding* overhead and doesn't give you any scalability benefit.

On ASP.NET, if you have CPU-bound work to do, just call that method directly. Don't wrap it in `Task.Run`.

Comment: Setting aside the additional Azure upload piece (which is not CPU bound) for a moment - I understood that the threads processing web api requests are "special", and that we could free them up during long-running tasks with code like the above (because it executes on a non-"special" thread), and that that was good. I'm guessing some part of what I understood is incorrect, but I'm not clear which piece. And then, if we re-introduce the Azure upload piece?

Comment: The only thing "special" about them is that they have a request context. They're still thread pool threads, from the same thread pool that `Task.Run` uses, and by "stealing" these threads and "injecting" them later, you can throw off the heuristics of the thread pool. So there's (almost) no use case for `Task.Run` on ASP.NET at all. An Azure upload would be I/O-bound and therefore a perfect fit for `async`. Since you have mixed work (CPU-bound, then I/O-bound), do the CPU-bound work synchronously and then the I/O-bound work asynchronously. Don't use `Task.Run`.

Comment: Great! We're getting to the root of my misunderstanding! We can't run this CPU-bound code on a non-ThreadPool thread, and there is no simple way to change that behavior (I don't want to offload to a service, for example)?

Comment: Well, you could *technically* create a new non-threadpool thread and execute the code. But again, that doesn't really buy you anything; the ASP.NET thread pool heuristics assume that ASP.NET controls all the threads. Offloading CPU-bound work to an Azure Worker role or Azure Job is not a bad idea; I would certainly consider it if the work was significant. But in that case you'd need to figure out what to return to the client before the work is complete, and some way to notify the client that the work is complete.

Answer (score 2):

You could see performance and responsiveness improvements for your asp.net application if it is using too many threads from the thread pool, which can happen if you have a lot of long running requests. If the request queue becomes full, the web server rejects requests with an HTTP 503 status (Server Too Busy). According to Microsoft, there are cases where the performance benefit of async code can be significant:

> A web application  using synchronous methods to service high latency calls where the    thread pool grows to the .NET 4.5 default maximum  of 5, 000 threads would consume approximately 5 GB more memory than an application able the service the same requests using asynchronous methods and only 50 threads. When you’re doing asynchronous work, you’re not always using a thread. For example, when you make an asynchronous web service request, ASP.NET will not be using any threads between the async method call and the await.  Using the thread pool to service requests with high latency can lead to a large memory footprint and poor utilization of the server hardware

This however, is not the case for CPU-bound operations, only **network-bound or I/O-bound**.

For more information, have a look at [Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4), which applies to web hosted Web API applications as well.

Comment: The thing is, he is not reducing the number of running threads at all.

Comment: Can you be more specific? How many concurrent requests have you tried and what is the size of the thread pool?